# Как запустить Unirest на с#

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь подключить либу Unirest я понимаю что здесь все написано http://unirest.io/net но не могу понять что надо вписать и как создать MyClass

сам код который тестирую

```
HttpResponse<MyClass> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
.header("accept", "application/json")
.field("parameter", "value")
.field("foo", "bar")
.asJson<MyClass>();
```

На данный момент ошибки лезут

The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'unirest_net.request.HttpRequest' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>

Comment: А вы `MyClass` то где-нибудь реализовали хоть?

Comment: Он же не возникнет сам по себе. Его надо где-нибудь определить

Comment: нет я его ни создавал, в манах ничего об этом ни сказано и что в этом классе MyClass должно быть тоже не понятно

Comment: Ну я так понимаю зависит от:

Comment: .field("parameter", "value") .field("foo", "bar")

Comment: нашел на en.stackoverflow.com совет написать так HttpResponse<stirng> не помогло.
@Сергей а можно кусок кода как рабочий вариант, я вообще не знаю с# но пытаюсь кусами как-то его понимать

Comment: я не знаю unirest - так что не могу вам рабочий код дать. Я бы мог разобраться, но не имею на это свободного  времени. Может кто другой поможет. Но лично вам я советую пока оставить попытки учить язык с такого высокого уровня и перейти к основам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак. В ходе эксперимента

```
var gif_id = "feqkVgjJpYtjy";
unirest_net.http.HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = unirest_net.http.Unirest.get("https://giphy.p.mashape.com/v1/gifs/"+gif_id+"?api_key=dc6za123")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "SNERVLqh5Omshu9HNTnca3coHgwop10IrHw123")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.asJson<string>();

return  jsonResponse.Body;
```

Мы получили некий [json](https://pastebin.com/MxPnNue5). Я обычно в таких случаях, чтоб не особо парится иду на онлайновые сервисы например на https://jsonutils.com/. Вставляем туда этот самый json и получаем такую вот партянку классов (сложный json достаточно, ничего не поделаешь - в принципе не всегда имеет смысл настолько полно его покрывать, и все это можно порезать до минимально необходимого вам уровня - и все будет прекрасно десериализовываться, но мне не известно что именно вам из всего этого надо, поэтому вот:

```
public class User
{
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string banner_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_url { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string twitter { get; set; }
}

public class FixedHeightStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class OriginalStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidth
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedHeightSmallStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedHeightDownsampled
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class Preview
{
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedHeightSmall
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class DownsizedStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class Downsized
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class DownsizedLarge
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidthSmallStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class PreviewWebp
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidthStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidthSmall
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class DownsizedSmall
{
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidthDownsampled
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class DownsizedMedium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class Original
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string frames { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
}

public class FixedHeight
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
    public string webp { get; set; }
    public string webp_size { get; set; }
}

public class Looping
{
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
}

public class OriginalMp4
{
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string mp4 { get; set; }
    public string mp4_size { get; set; }
}

public class PreviewGif
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}

public class 480wStill
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public FixedHeightStill fixed_height_still { get; set; }
    public OriginalStill original_still { get; set; }
    public FixedWidth fixed_width { get; set; }
    public FixedHeightSmallStill fixed_height_small_still { get; set; }
    public FixedHeightDownsampled fixed_height_downsampled { get; set; }
    public Preview preview { get; set; }
    public FixedHeightSmall fixed_height_small { get; set; }
    public DownsizedStill downsized_still { get; set; }
    public Downsized downsized { get; set; }
    public DownsizedLarge downsized_large { get; set; }
    public FixedWidthSmallStill fixed_width_small_still { get; set; }
    public PreviewWebp preview_webp { get; set; }
    public FixedWidthStill fixed_width_still { get; set; }
    public FixedWidthSmall fixed_width_small { get; set; }
    public DownsizedSmall downsized_small { get; set; }
    public FixedWidthDownsampled fixed_width_downsampled { get; set; }
    public DownsizedMedium downsized_medium { get; set; }
    public Original original { get; set; }
    public FixedHeight fixed_height { get; set; }
    public Looping looping { get; set; }
    public OriginalMp4 original_mp4 { get; set; }
    public PreviewGif preview_gif { get; set; }
    public 480wStill 480w_still { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string bitly_gif_url { get; set; }
    public string bitly_url { get; set; }
    public string embed_url { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public string content_url { get; set; }
    public string source_tld { get; set; }
    public string source_post_url { get; set; }
    public int is_indexable { get; set; }
    public int is_sticker { get; set; }
    public string import_datetime { get; set; }
    public string trending_datetime { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string response_id { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

Собственно как-то так мы получили требуемый `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено!
Там где `<MyClass>` поменял на `<string>`.

```
var gif_id = "feqkVgjJpYtjy";
unirest_net.http.HttpResponse<string> jsonResponse = unirest_net.http.Unirest.get("https://giphy.p.mashape.com/v1/gifs/"+gif_id+"?api_key=dc6za123")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "SNERVLqh5Omshu9HNTnca3coHgwop10IrHw123")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.asJson<string>();

return  jsonResponse.Body;
```

Comment: Да, хотел такое предложить, но не был уверен, что это хорошая идея. Там по сути должно на класс десериализовываться - чтоб можно было легко узнать, что куда. А проецирование на string - это так себе костылик. Но да ладно.

Comment: А выложите содержимое стринга. Состряпаем вам MyClass

Comment: а string класса у меня в коде нету, я просто через знаки <> добавил и это сработало. Может здесь будет ответ http://unirest.io/net
Или через nuget скачать либу и там уже как-то понять. 

Было бы здорова если бы у вас получилось собрать MyClass как  в примере

Comment: Класс `string` - он встроенный(базовый) в `.net` - и есть всегда и везде.

Comment: Я имел в виду содержимое переменной jsonResponse

Comment: там очень большой json как его сюда скинуть ?

Comment: можно на https://pastebin.com/ закинуть и ссылкой сюда

Comment: есть https://pastebin.com/MxPnNue5

Comment: Ву а ля! Получите, распишитесь.

Comment: 1) сначала ругался на этот класс public class 480wStill 
я его удалил и удалил те строки на которые ссылается.
2) после удаление public class 480wStill пытается сделать запрос но потом ошибка тут  **Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'Data'**

Comment: Код покажите. Чую где то недосмотрели

Comment: @Сергей Вы были правы, я там не верно указал. РАБОТАЕТ!!! 
получается что использовать string выдает body как json
А использование MyClass позволяет обращаться к каждому полю или элементу как правильно. 

Теперь задумался в сравнение какой из способов лучше, так как кода много получилось.

Comment: Ну кода много и что? Он все равно не вручную сделан. Удалите все, что для вашей задачи не нужно и уже легче будет.

Comment: И последний вопрос а какова  вероятность что сервис https://jsonutils.com/ ни верно распарсить json и не верный выдаст результат ?

Comment: Ну есть небольшая что будет неадекватить, как с этим полем сегодня. Зависит от json еще - иногда бывает что он не для всех случаев на конкретной выборке подходит. Инструмент полезный, но необходимость головой думать не отменяет.

Comment: Кстати, там есть однотипные классы - их можно в один слить.

Comment: @Сергей как ? 
И еще заметил использовать разные запросы под api то предыдущие классы уже не работают. Ругается что нельзя использовать MyClass для десериализации.

пример1) https://giphy.p.mashape.com/v1/gifs?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&ids=feqkVgjJpYtjy%2C7rzbxdu0ZEXLy 

пример2)  https://giphy.p.mashape.com/v1/gifs/feqkVgjJpYtjy?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC 

разный json

Comment: Для разных запросов надо по новой прогонять, но опят же, некоторые классы будут из раза в раз повторяться, так что переиспользовать их нужно. Как, слить повторяющиеся классы? ну например есть два класса  FixedHeightStill, OriginalStill (их там больше, но я просто покажу принцип) смотрим - поля у них одинаковые, значит это одно и то же. Один переименовываем в Still - остальные удаляем и всех их упоминания заменяем на Still. И так со всеми остальными классами которые имеют наглость повторяться.

Comment: Я в свое время когда покрывал VkAPI очень много классов запилил таким образом. Работа кропотливая и нудная, но никуда от нее не деться.